# How to set encoding in scala sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible like in maven:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

google shows not results for sbt.

Comment: See https://github.com/scalameta/metals/issues/1424. I think if you do `scalacOptions ++= Seq("encoding", "utf-8")` or something like that, it should work

Answer (score 0):

"Google shows not results for sbt." is besides the truth. If you analyze it, is this a scalac compiler option.
[Here the answer](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html#use-compiler-options-with-sbt) Caution, option and argument on same line.
(And use a better Google.)